# Hibernate without Java EE 6

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, websphere, java-ee-6

I have Websphere 7 server, and it don't support JPA 2.0. So I can't run on WAS 7 JPA 2.0 applications.

But I'm wondering how Spring users run Hibernate on Tomcat or Jetty? This servlet-containers also (as WAS 7) doesn't support Java EE 6.

*So it's mean that I can run Hibernate on WAS 7 with the same results as on the Tomcat or Jetty?*.

If yes, what are benefits of using app-servers for JPA? Why all developers don't use servlet-containers instead app-servers?

Also I heard about "container-managed" stuff, that allows some additional features and functionality. So it's mean that many developers (who uses Spring on Jetty and Tomcat) don't get benefits of using container-managed features of app-servers?

P.S. I know about available `Feature Pack` patch for WAS 7 for JPA 2.0 support, but question not about it.

Comment: Why can't you run JPA2 applications in WAS 7? Are you running into naming or library conflicts with older versions of Hibernate? JPA itself doesn't require you to run it in a container, so is the integration problem happening with legacy code?

Comment: @Per: WAS7 is a Java EE 5 container and ships with JPA1. You can't flawlessly upgrade it to JPA2 via webapp-provided libraries.

Comment: @MyTitle - try [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?124644-JPA2-with-spring-data-deployed-on-Websphere-7-WITHOUT-Websphere-JPA2-feature-pack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application servers offer a set of services "out of the box", so they are easier to use *if the offered services are the ones you need*. You just package and deploy your application and the thing works. Furthermore, most of the technologies are instantiated by the application server, so you avoid a lot of classloader issues.

The problem with application servers is that sometimes (quite often, actually), you need to pick and choose particular versions of particular frameworks, services, etc that are incompatible with those which the application server offers. In those cases, you usually need to fiddle with the application server, and in some cases, what you would like to do might not even be possible with your application server.

For example, Weblogic 10.x is a Java EE 5 application server and so it will offer by default JSF 1.2 and JPA 1. If you want to use something newer, you need to manually deploy some additional libraries (JSF 2.0), or patch the server (JPA 2.0).

Another example: with Glassfish 3.1 I have not been able to use Tomcat EL intead of Glassfish EL. Tomcat EL supports varargs method call while Glassfish EL does not.

That rigidness of Java EE application servers makes a lot of people prefer developing for a standalone servlet container such as Tomcat or Jetty, where you have *nothing* out of the box but the Servlet and JSP APIs, but you can manually put *everything* inside. You can also package it with your application, which is more comfortable when you are developing, but can give you problems if you deploy more than one application per container (waste of resources, classloading issues, classloader leaks, ...)

**UPDATE:**

There are *some* differences in using JPA in a SE environment (such as Tomcat) when compared to using JPA inside a Java EE container. Basically:

- You have to manually manage `EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager` instances.
- Tomcat does not do injection so `@PersistenceContext` annotation and similar ones do not work.

Note that some containers (such as Spring) can be configured to hide these details, so you can work exactly as if you were inside a Java EE container.

Read [the JPA spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html) for details on running in SE environments instead of EE environments.

Regarding another libraries, in general you will find some minor differences. For example, JAX-WS requires registering a servlet and a listener for your webapp, but anything else should be identical. Usually you can search the documentation for instructions on how to run the thing inside a standalone servlet container.

Comment: Thanks, very liked your answer. So I there is no difference where to put JPA 2.0-implementation libraries: to WAS7 or to Tomcat? I mean int this case no difference between functionality, i.e. all the things which I can do in Tomcat with JPA 2.0 (Hibernate), with _same_ result  I can do with WAS 7?

Answer (score 5):

You can bring in a lot of functionality by including the appropriate jars in your WEB-INF/lib folder, but then the servlet container cannot help you in any way with the functionality, and it will most likely not be well integrated with the functionalty actually provided by the container.  A typical example is bringing your own JSF 2.0 libraries.

The real advantages of using implementations in the container, is that the container can then help with clustering across multiple hosts, providing JDBC connection pools, etc.

So, you need to be more careful when including e.g. Hibernate yourself, and do all the configuration inside your own deployment, but it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

You could just as well ask an exactly opposite question: "why use bare servlet containers with JPA 2 since it is included in all the Java EE 6 servers?".

Basically it boils down to either:

- having a light-weight container and then a heavy application (the Spring way),
- having a light-weight application and then a heavy container (the Java EE 6 way).

After years of evolution, the models of building the applications with Spring and Java EE 6 have converged to the point where sometimes you cannot really tell just by looking at a class, whether it's a Spring or a CDI bean. So the real difference is mostly in configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JPA 2.0 feature pack for WAS 7.0, which may help you.